# How to use artifacts from upstream projects in jenkins?

Tags: jakarta-ee, build-automation, jenkins

I want to deploy an EAR file from an upstream project in a Jenkins build pipeline, where the filename is dynamically generated using jenkins environment variables eg

```
myEar_2011-11-08_14-21-06_521.ear
```

The file is then archived. How can I reference this file in the downstream project that does the actual deploy? I see the option for

```
This build is parameterized : 
    Build selector for Copy Artifact 
        Name - ???
        Default Selector - Upstream build that triggered this job
```

What do I put in 'Name' and how do i get a reference the EAR file?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use wildcards in the nameing.  I think that using a Name value like this might work:

```
myEar_*.ear
```

You might need to add extra path if the archived file isn't at the top level.

We use a similar approach in several of our jobs where the name of the file is date-and-build dependent.